# Unit Testing a Table

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, unit-testing

I'm getting into Unit Testing for the first time, and trying to test a `UITableView` that is in my `UITableViewController`, but I'm getting failed tests.

**This should have 1 subview for the 1 `UITableView` but I get an error "View does not have a table subview".**

```
- (void)testParentViewHasTableViewSubview
{
    NSArray *subviews = self.vcToTest.view.subviews;
    XCTAssertTrue([subviews containsObject:self.vcToTest.tableView], @"View does not have a table subview");
}
```

**This should have exactly 6 rows because that information is hardcoded, but I think because my `UITableView` is coming up as nil I get an error "Table has 0 rows but it should have 6".**

```
- (void)testTableViewNumberOfRowsInSection
{
    NSInteger expectedRows = 6;
    XCTAssertTrue([self.vcToTest tableView:self.vcToTest.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]==expectedRows, @"Table has %ld rows but it should have %ld", (long)[self.vcToTest tableView:self.vcToTest.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0], (long)expectedRows);
}
```

I don't know if it has to do with the `UITableView` coming with the `UITableViewController` instead of the `UITableView` being added as an outlet to a `UIViewController`, or what exactly. All of my other simple tests are working (conforms to table view data source, is connected to delegate, etc.).

Has anyone been through this before?

Here is my `setUp`:

```
- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    self.vcToTest = [[TableViewController alloc] init];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    self.vcToTest = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"testTableView"];
    [self.vcToTest performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Comment: You might consider using UI Tests instead of Unit Tests. UI Tests allow you to record a step of user activities and query the user interface.

Comment: @Palle so just do this same thing but instead in my `UITests.m` file?

Comment: You should have a look at [UI Testing in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/406/) from WWDC 2015.